# line [: missing `]' debugging help please

Tags: shell

I have written this script as a module in installing postgres and this is to show the user that the database has been created and get his/her input as to they see the database was created. When I run the script, I get the error

```
./dbtest: line 39: [: missing `]'
```

I have tried adding " " around yes and '' around yes and I can't figure out what is missing. The script is as follows

```sh
#   
#
# Check to make sure the database was created and who is the owner
#
#
 if [ -f showdb ];

 then 
      cp showdb /home

 else
      echo " show database file is missing "

fi

if [ -f /home/showdb ];

 then
       su - postgres -c '/home/showdb'

       echo " Do you see the data name created listed above? "
       echo " "
       echo " Type yes or no (type out the whole word please) "
       echo " "
       read dbawr

            if [ $dbawr == yes && $dbawr == Yes ];

                then 

                     echo "Great!"
                     exit

                else
                     echo " Please contact tech support "
                     pause " Press [CTRL] [Z] to exit the program now " 
              fi

  else

         echo " File Missing!!"

fi
```

What am I missing in this script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the boolean `&&` operator withing the single brackets conditional `[ test = test ]`.  If you're using bash (or a similar shell), the preferred syntax is to use the double brackets:

```
[[ this == this && that == that ]]
```

If you're worried about portability, then you should stick with the single brackets, but use them like so:

```
[ this = this ] && [ that = that ]
```

Note that I didn't use the double equals (`==`).  That's not posix compliant either.

Comment: You can, however, use `test`'s own logic options. `[ this = this -a that = that ]`

Comment: Good point, and a rigorous answer would have included that.  However, I (and [many others](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#A.5B)) generally prefer to see it as separate tests rather than separated by `-a` and `-o`, especially as the tests become more complex.

Good catch though ;)